# How can I easily reinstall all uninstalled VS Code extensions that have their files still lingering in my ~/.vscode/extensions folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I messed up and deleted an extension I shouldn't have uninstalled but like uninstalled extensions are all still in the folder and I don't wanna manually install back everything I uninstalled so is there a way to just install everything

I tried many commands to get the extensions and install them but that only got already installed extensions code --list-extensions --show-versions > extensions4.txt
and then i tried just getting all the folder names but the format needs to be {name}@{version} for installing but the folders arent named accordingly so like idk what to do they are so many and i dont know how to (on windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows(CMD)
Kinda buggy and some extensions fail to install

go to the extensions folder for vs code

open it

open command prompt and cd into the extensions folder

run this command

```bash
dir "C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions" /b > extensions.txt
```

you will get a file with all the sub folders in the folder but the names will have this format {name}-{version} and we need {name}@{version} to install things properly so we need to use this python script

```py
with open("C:\\Users\\%USERPROFILE%\\.vscode\\extensions\\extensions.txt", "r") as f:
    filenames = f.readlines()

for filename in filenames:
    filename = filename.strip()  # Remove newline character at the end of the line
    name_parts = filename.split('-')  # Split the filename by the dash character
    version_index = None
    for i, part in enumerate(name_parts):
        if part[0].isdigit():  # Check if the first character of the part is a digit
            version_index = i  # Save the index of the part that contains the version number
            break  # Stop looking for the version number
    if version_index is not None:
        name_parts[version_index] = '@' + name_parts[version_index]  # Add @ symbol before the version number
    new_name = '-'.join(name_parts).replace('@.', '.')  # Create the new filename
    new_name1 = new_name.replace("-@", "@")
    print(new_name1)
```

copy the output in the terminal which will be {name}@{version} and save it to the same extensions.txt file in the folder

then go back to cmd and run this command

```bash
for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in (extensions.txt) do code --install-extension %i
```

all extensions will start to be installed

**IMPORTANT DETAIL**
*when you run the first command the file may have 1 or 2 files that are in the extensions folder like the extensions.json so delete those from the extensions.txt file*

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following using [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq). To install the extensions named by directories in your `${HOME}/.vscode/extenions` folder, try the following:

`find "${HOME}/.vscode/extensions" -maxdepth 2 -name 'package.json' | xargs -I % jq -r '.publisher+"."+.name' -- % | xargs -I % code '--install-extension %'`

It's a bit janky of an approach and relies on the UNIX `find` command (sorry). If you're on Windows and you're doing dev work, your probably already have Git Bash though, so you can run it from there.